# How can I stop Windows VMs from auto screenlock after X minutes?

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, vmware

I connect to multiple VMWare instances via (mstsc - remote desktop from my Win10 machine).
Recently, after a windows update or possible a policy change, all of the VMs screen lock after X minutes (I'm guessing the value is 10).

**What I've Tried**

I've altered the registry and added the value, NoLockScreen, and I've rebooted, but the machines still lock : (found the solution at [https://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-disable-the-Windows-10-lock-screen/](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-disable-the-windows-10-lock-screen/).

Reg location :

```
\\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Personalization
```

[image: nolockscreen]

All of the various windows machines seem to lock though the different VMs are running 2012 R2, Server 2016, and basic Win10.

**All On Same Domain**

All the VMs and my client run on the same domain.  My client (where I remote from to the VMs) is :

[image: win version]

This problem causes me to have to type in my password every time on the multiple machines I connect to — total waste of time.

Is there any other way around this that works?

Comment: Have you tried another Remoting software?  It seems that all of the VMs started acting the same way, but perhaps it's a local symptom instead of being on the VMs themselves.  By the way, please update the question : are these VMs all on the same domain, is your workstation on the same domain, and what is the precise OS version you're using (Windows 10v1903 for instance).

Comment: in Windows 10, there is a security policy for "interactive logon" due to machine inactivity, for default values check https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/interactive-logon-machine-inactivity-limit

Comment: @ChristopherHostage  Updated with requested info.

Comment: @M.Abdelhafid That's a very good article and I found the setting Interactive Logon: Machine inactivity limit set to 600 seconds (5 minutes).  That seems to be the setting I'm looking for but alas a network admin has to change it.  Thanks though.  That seems to be the answer and I will upvote and set to answer if you write it up.

Comment: Uh, yeah, 600 seconds is actually 10 minutes -- math and time are not my strong subjects. :)  And I came back too late to be able to edit original comment.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If You Don't Have Admin Rights**

If you don't have admin rights to make the change shown in the accepted solution, there is an automation way around this.

It was really annoying to have to type my password every time one of my various VMs would get locked so I wrote this C# script which I run in LINQPad (get your free copy at [linqpad.net](https://www.linqpad.net/)).

```
// #######################################################
// ####  Must include the two following libraries
// ####  using System.Diagnostics
// #### using System.Runtime.InteropServices

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto,ExactSpelling=true)]
private static extern IntPtr SetFocus(HandleRef hWnd);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

void Main()
{
    InitializeTimer();
    RescanTimer.Start();
}
System.Timers.Timer RescanTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
private void InitializeTimer()
{
    // ## The timer will run the code every 10 seconds (10000ms).
    // ##  You can change it to whatever interval you like that is 
    // ##  shorter than your LockScreen time
    RescanTimer.Interval = 10000D;
    RescanTimer.Elapsed += RescanTimer_Elapsed;
}

protected void RescanTimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    try{
        //Stop timer each time, while the elapsed function runs.
        RescanTimer.Stop();
        Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
        foreach (Process process in processlist)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(process.MainWindowTitle))
            {
                if (process.ProcessName.Contains("mstsc")){
                // ## finds processes which are mstsc and gets associated main window
                    Console.WriteLine("Process: {0} ID: {1} Window title: {2}", process.ProcessName, process.Id, process.MainWindowTitle);
                    SetForegroundWindow(process.MainWindowHandle);
                    SetFocus(new HandleRef(null, process.MainWindowHandle));
                    ShowWindow(process.MainWindowHandle, 1);
                }
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    finally{
        // ## Insure that even if the elapsed function fails, 
        // ## the timer is still restarted.
        RescanTimer.Start();
    }
}
```

**Working Solution**

I've been running this code for a couple of hours now and I found that:

1. it doesn't use any noticeable CPU
2. none of the associated VM screens have locked
3. it doesn't interrupt you or shift your focus to another screen (while I was typing up this answer, the code ran numerous times without interrupting)

**Create A Separate App**

Of course you can use the code and write a small .exe for yourself if you like so you don't have to run LINQPad.

**Output Mostly For Testing**

The Console output is mostly for my testing.  It will look like the following (your process IDs and computer names will obviously be different):

[image: output example]

Comment: Nice solution. This actually works with other processes as well. I am using it from Microsoft Store's Remote Desktop app and it's process name is RdClient.Windows

Comment: @raddevus I am trying to use this solution but I have never used LinqPad or C#. I suppose this is supposed to run as "C# Program" language, right? Trying to do so, however, results in "CS0305 Using the generic type 'HandleRef<THandle>' requires 1 type arguments" error. Would you be able to elaborate somewhat more on how to set this up properly?

Comment: Never mind, figured it out!

EDIT: Just kidding! For posterity: go to Query > References and Properties > Namespace Imports and check if `System.Diagnostics` and `System.Runtime.InteropServices` are there. If not, write them in.

Comment: @Eleshar Just checked SO for the 1st time today.  Hey, I actually show the following items are needed for this script -- press F4 in LinqPad to set these up: 1) additional references `System.Windows.Forms.dll`  2) 3 additional namespace imports: a) `System.Diagnostics` b) `System.Runtime.InteropServices` c) `System.Windows.Forms`
Hope that helps -- good luck

Comment: @raddevus Yes and no, I made the script run, however it didn't block my VM rom screenlocking. What did help though was to create a random Power Automate for Desktop script (basically infinite loop doing nothing), which is running in Edit mode. This apparently counts as a sufficient activity for the VM. Unfortunately I gotta stay connected to it in some way, but locking my physical machine and preventing it from going to sleep is apparently sufficient for that.

Comment: @Eleshar I've also discovered that you can create a PowerPoint (if you have MS PowerPoint), create one blank slide and start the slideshow.  Don't click on the slideshow at all but just Alt-Tab to other processes so the slideshow runs in the background.  As long as the slideshow continues to run your VM won't (shouldn't) lock.    Works on mine.  

Answer (score 3):

According to your question and comments here is the response

---

### Interactive logon: Machine inactivity limit

It's a security policy started since Windows 8 and applies also to Windows 10.

Windows notices inactivity of a logon session, and if the amount of inactive time exceeds the inactivity limit, then the lock screen will come up, locking the session.

> Default Value: **not enforced**.

### How to change it?

- Hit <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd> button.
- Type **Local Security Policy**
- follow the instructions on the imgae below:

[image]

> **P.S:** If you are a local administrator you can change it from **Local Security Policy**, otherwise a help-desk admin can modify it for you

Source: [Microsoft Docs- interactive logon: machine inactivity limit](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/interactive-logon-machine-inactivity-limit)